# if else statement not working properly

Tags: java, if-statement

this is my first time using this forum and I am new to the whole Java experience, so forgive me if this is a really simple fix.

I am trying to make this project for school, but I can't get my if else statement to work.
As you can see, if you enter melee or ranged everything is alright, but if you don't it redirects you.
My problem is that even if you type melee or ranged, it will first direct you to the if method, and after that it will immediately redirect you to the else statement.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

```
newchamp.Type = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What type of champion have you summoned? (melee or ranged)", "Type", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("melee")) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You have now confirmed your champion, you can not edit anything from this point on.");
        }
        if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("ranged")) {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You have now confirmed your champion, you can not edit anything from this point on.");
        }
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You can only choose Melee or Ranged!");
            newchamp.Type = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What type of champion have you summoned? (Melee or Ranged)", "Type", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You have now confirmed your champion, you can not edit anything from this point on.");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `newchamp.Type != Type`

Comment: use else if for second if, ie if(Type.equalsIgnoreCase("ranged"))

Comment: I think it's better to use switch case statement. If you add some new type you must add new if else statement and code became more and more unreadable

Answer (score 6):

Your code:

```
if(a) ...
if(b) ... else ...
```

So in every cases (`a` `true` or `false`) if `b` is `false` it will goes into the `else` statement (to be more specific, if the `Type` is not equal to `ranged`, the `else` part will be executed).

I think what you want is

```
if(a) ... else if(b) ... else ...
```

Using your code:

```
if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("melee")) {

} else if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("ranged")) {

} else {

}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use an `if`, `else if`, `else` construct.

```
if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("melee")) {
  // ...
}
else if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("ranged")) {
  // ...
}
else {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this

```
String   type = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What type of champion have you summoned? (melee or ranged)", "Type", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("melee")) {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You have now confirmed your champion, you can not edit anything from this point on.");
            }else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("ranged")) {
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You have now confirmed your champion, you can not edit anything from this point on.");
            }
            else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You can only choose Melee or Ranged!");
               type = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What type of champion have you summoned? (Melee or Ranged)", "Type", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You have now confirmed your champion, you can not edit anything from this point on.");
            }
```

Comment: Instead of a copy paste, can you indent the code? and avoid the scroll bar?

Comment: What do you have against scrolling?

Comment: it makes your answer unreadable, imagine you are sending your code to a code review. Here it is not well indented and lines are too long... Your reviewer will not take the time to review this kind of code

Comment: For somes beginners this is very important

Answer (score 1):

Does

```
newchamp.Type = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What type of champion have you summoned? (melee or ranged)", "Type", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("melee")) {
       ..something..
    }
    else if (Type.equalsIgnoreCase("ranged")) {
          ..something..
    }
    else {
       ..something..
    }
}
}
```

work for you?

Comment: Instead of a copy paste, can you indent the code? and avoid the scroll bar?

Comment: Yeah, I am sorry about that. I will do better next time, thanks for the advice!